# Mysterious early morning cellular data usage

Tags: wifi, iphone, ios, cellular-data

On my iphone 4s, there are these cellular data usages ranging from 1MB to 80 MB between 1 AM to 3 AM. This happens everyday. anybody knows what's going on and how to avoid it? During that time I am sleeping and the phone is connected to the WiFi.

Secondly I have noticed that when I lock my phone, it starts using cellular data instead of WiFi!!!

I have iOS 8.

Try checking your data usage history, as it seems like a known issue. A lot of people did complain but I can not find a solution to it.

Comment: Your phone disables the wifi antenna after your phones been locked for a period of time.  It sounds like an app is making a network call probably using Background App Refresh

Comment: Did you identify which app is using this data? You can check that on Settings > Cellular.

Answer (score 1):

It could be something like this secret (well, not so secret any more) program as detailed in the [Wall Street Journal](http://www.wsj.com/articles/americans-cellphones-targeted-in-secret-u-s-spy-program-1415917533):

> Updated Nov. 13, 2014 8:22 p.m. ET
>
> WASHINGTON—The Justice Department is scooping up data from thousands
>   of mobile phones through devices deployed on airplanes that mimic
>   cellphone towers, a high-tech hunt for criminal suspects that is
>   snagging a large number of innocent Americans, according to people
>   familiar with the operations.
>
> The U.S. Marshals Service program, which became fully functional
>   around 2007, operates Cessna aircraft from at least five
>   metropolitan-area airports, with a flying range covering most of the
>   U.S. population, according to people familiar with the program.

I've noticed the same thing myself, and I hear light planes flying over my greater NYC area home in the early morning several times a week. Because I'm a bit paranoid, I turn off my phone at night.